# Looking to convert this JAVA/PHP Encryption code to C#

Tags: php, encryption

I work in PHP and looking to convert a piece of code from JAVA/PHP to C# related to encryption , I am novice in C# can anyone help me?

Code is picked from http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php

Also given below - Please help me :

====================================================

/**********/
/**PHP**/

```
    <?php 

    class MCrypt
    {
            private $iv = 'fedcba9876543210'; #Same as in JAVA
            private $key = '0123456789abcdef'; #Same as in JAVA


            function __construct()
            {
            }

            function encrypt($str) {

              //$key = $this->hex2bin($key);    
              $iv = $this->iv;

              $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);

              mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
              $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);

              mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
              mcrypt_module_close($td);

              return bin2hex($encrypted);
            }

            function decrypt($code) {
              //$key = $this->hex2bin($key);
              $code = $this->hex2bin($code);
              $iv = $this->iv;

              $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);

              mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
              $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);

              mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
              mcrypt_module_close($td);

              return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
            }

            protected function hex2bin($hexdata) {
              $bindata = '';

              for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
                    $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
              }

              return $bindata;
            }

    }
```

Comment: thats AES CBC encryption.  I'm no c# expert but it's a fairly standard algo that most likely ships with core c#

Answer (score 0):

Look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9df14hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (MicroSoft Developer Network),
at the end of the page there are some examples called RijndaelManaged_Example that show how to encrypt and decypt

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9df14hc(v=vs.110).aspx